# Any way to make CSS visibility work when nested?

Tags: css

So I always thought if the parent container has a property set, it supercedes the child.  So in my case I want the parent container to be hidden, but the child elements have a visibility of visible.  But it seems the child elements visibility property supercedes the parents and thus will still show.

But the twist is if using display property, it works the way I want.  Here is the html:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <a href="">title</a>
</div>

<div class="wrap2">
    <a href="">title2</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap { visibility:hidden; }
.wrap a { visibility:visible; }

.wrap2 { display:none; }
.wrap2 a { display:block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yPXtB/

So what I want is the ability to hide the container if I set the visibility to hidden even if the child elements have visible.

Comment: Consider this analogy: you stick someone in jail, and the jail warden says "you're in the hole for a month". What you want to allow is the prisoner to say "No I'm not" and letting him walk out the door. You cannot make a child suddenly become visible even though its parent is not.

Answer (score 6):

Another workaround is to use `opacity` with values 0 and 1 instead of `visibility`.

(Though check out http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity for compatibility with too old browsers if it's important)

Answer (score 2):

If you need the child css to have visibility: visible, then you can't simply set the parent to hidden, because parent doesn't override the child.

You'd need to either set each individual child to hidden as well, or wrap the children again in another div with visibility: visible, and toggle that to hidden instead of the parent, i.e.:

```
<div class="hiddenwrap">
    <div class="visiblewrap"> /* toggle this instead */
        /* content without visibility properties */
    </div>
</div>

.hiddenwrap { visibility:hidden; }
.visiblewrap { visibility:visible; }
```

Comment: This issue stemmed from me using google web font loader...which assigns classes "loading" and "active" states of the font to prevent FOUT issue.  So in loading, the CSS is visibility:hidden; and "active, the CSS is visibility:visible...But on top of that, there is a container that needs to be visbility:hidden until another event happens before it becomes visible...quite complicated to explain clearly.

Comment: In that case, if you can't control the "active" css, you might just want to override it with something like: ".wrap .active {visibility: inherit;}", so you can toggle the parent again.

Answer (score 0):

`visibility: hidden` causes the element not to be drawn, but it is still there and even the space it occupies stays occupied. The flow of the page isn't affected. Therefor it is possible to still draw the child in that space.

The child does use the parent's visibility if you don't specify it explicitly, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/yPXtB/2/

`display: none` not only hides the element, but removes it from the flow of the page as well. Display affects the way the element behaves and changes the flow. There is no more space to draw the child in.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain my situation.  I am not talking about the space...I simply want to hide the container with visibility, not display but the child elements have visible...

Comment: You said *'using display property, it works the way I want'*, so I figured you already have your solution. I just tried to explain the difference between them, hoping that you'd understand why it works the way it does.

Comment: No, I mentioned "display" to illustrate why it works with display and not visibility property...

Comment: Does the child's visibility must be set? It will retain the parent's invisibility if not set to visible.

Comment: I think you primary thought is wrong: *'So I always thought if the parent container has a property set, it supercedes the child.'* This is not true. If you set the font of the parent to 'Arial', the child will be 'Arial' too, unless you set it to 'Tahoma' for the child explicitly, in that case it will just use 'Tahoma' and ignore the font property of the parent. Same goes for visibility. Only display is different, because it actually changes the flow, so removing the parent from the flow causes all children to be dragged along, disregarding their own display property.

Comment: Well then there is no way around my issue...I am using google web font loader which lets me assign elements to be hidden until the font is ready, then it switches to visible or else you will get the FOUT issue.  But I also have a container around that font element that I need hidden until I need it...