# Angular2 Nested Visibility

Tags: css, angular

I am implementing a recursive component that displays tabs and uses visibility to show only the active content.  I choose this approach because the tab contents are expensive to generate and to layout from a DOM perspective.

[based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890285/any-way-to-make-css-visibility-work-when-nested), i see that when i hide a tab, the nested child tabs are still visible.

I am thinking that the best way to handle this is by creating a set of css classes:

1. p-visible
2. p-visible-hidden

This way, I can recurse through the DOM elements when a tab is set to hidden and change any elements having a p-visible class to having the p-visible-hidden class instead.  Similarly, when a tab is set to visible, i can switch all of the elements that have the p-visible-hidden class to p-visible.

So I'm wondering the best way to implement this in Angular2 - To me, the best way maybe to actually select the child DOM elements.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

[test harness for component](https://github.com/datumgeek/plotter-view-samples-angular2/blob/master/views/tabLayoutTest/tabLayoutTest.component.ts)

[tab layout component](https://github.com/datumgeek/plotter-shell-angular2/blob/master/src/layouts/tabLayout/tabLayout.component.ts)

Comment: oh, the <p-compose> component is pretty sweet.  it finds a remote module located on some other external web server, compiles the module, grabs the component factory, and creates an instance of the component inside the <p-compose> component

[p-compose component](https://github.com/datumgeek/plotter-shell-angular2/blob/master/src/compose/compose.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by creating an @Input boolean (called parentVisible) that indicates if the parent is visible or hidden.  This property is cascaded down through the recursive hierarchy of components.

The parentVisible boolean is an additional filter on setting each child element's visibility (if parentVisible is false, the visibility is set to hidden, if parentVisible is true, then set the visiblity as before)

This strategy makes it possible to avoid direct DOM manipulation which is deemed good for unit testing and doing things in the Angular2 way :smile: